# Software that lists other installed softwares on PC & lists if their updates are available.

Tags: windows-8

I am currently running Windows 8.1 on my PC.

I have set all the softwares on my PC to manually update to the latest available version.
I switch between ISP & would want only a specific ISP(unlimited internet pack) for updating softwares. That's the reason I've disabled automatic update.

Is there a software that list all other softwares installed on the PC & also lists if an update to them is available to download?
Because, currently I have to manually check each software/website if an update is available after 15 days or so.

Something like Google play which list all the apps & whether an update is available to them but for PC

Comment: The easy answer is switch to almost any linux distribution where this sort of behaviour is the norm.